# Using Search Function To Remove Div Elements Dynamically W/ Out Page Reload

Tags: php, css, search, html

This is what my code does so far. It will help in understanding my question.

[Research Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZvco.png)

When you click on the parent div (the entire bar where the stock name is) the child div lowers down (I am accordion 1).

I'm still fairly new to HMTL and CSS (Learned it 2 days ago) and have successfully implemented someone's JavaScript to create the animation effect.

My question is this. Is there a method to remove the divs dynamically using a search function? In other words, can I remove a div based on search strings, WITHOUT reloading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reloading the page meens in Javascript.

It's totally doable..

For example, if you have jQuery installed :

Let's say you have a search field that (when submited) delete all div matching the search in their NAME properties :

```
HTML :
<input type="text" id="search" />
<input type="button" onclick="delete()" />

JS :
function delete() {
    search = jQuery('#search').val(); //retrieve the searched string
    jQuery('div[name="' + search + '"]').remove(); //search for DIV(s) with that NAME and removes it
}
```

Comment: Awesome, so here's a dumb question. Does JQuery come with a browser? I'm programming this for a mobile device and need to stay as standard as possible.

Comment: No jQuery is a cross-platform Javascript framework. It's one of the most used and the most adopted by public. If you need to code some javascript, you definitely need it (or an equivalent framework) as native browser javascript isn't pretty userfriendly. And yes it's ok for a very large amount of mobile devices. It's very easy to install. See : http://jquery.com/ Accept answer if it's ok to you ;)